# How to reset the doctrine query builder avoiding error message : line 0, col 83 near 'b': Error: 'b' is already defined

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am wrinting a software from scratch. Inside the homepage I want to show authors and books. To do this I use to make three queries:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(
        Request $request
    ) {
        $numberOfBooks = $this->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('count(b.id) as number')
            ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Book', 'b')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();

        $numberOfAuthors = $this->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('count(b.id) as number')
            ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Author', 'b')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();

        $allBooks = $this->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('b')
            ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Book', 'b')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'numberOfBooks' => $numberOfBooks,
            'numberOfAuthors' => $numberOfAuthors,
            'allBooks' => $allBooks,
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And it is ok: all works fine.

[image]

Yes, ... but after I started to refactor some code.

```
    $builder = $this->get('doctrine')
        ->getManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder();

    $numberOfBooks = $builder
        ->select('count(b.id) as number')
        ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Book', 'b')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    $numberOfAuthors = $builder
        ->select('count(b.id) as number')
        ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Author', 'b')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    $allBooks = $builder
        ->select('b')
        ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Book', 'b')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

I got this error message

[image]

I know how to fix this. But I want to know if I can "reset" the query builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this please:

```
    $manager = $this->get('doctrine')
        ->getManager();

    $numberOfBooks = $manager
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('count(b.id) as number')
        ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Book', 'b')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    $numberOfAuthors = $manager
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('count(b.id) as number')
        ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Author', 'b')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    $allBooks = $manager
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('b')
        ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Book', 'b')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

For the entityManager exist a function called `clear` to reinitialize It, but I think that in your case is better to call many createQueryBuilder every time you need a new query

Comment: is it good practice to create a new querybuilder for each new query?

Comment: it depends on your application and data.